# IBM db2 update substring in column

Tags: db2

I have a table X with column Y (IBM db2) where column Y is a string of length less than 2048 characters. Some values in column Y contains string like *ID some_value*. I would like to remove all those keys and values. For example:

Row before update:

some text a ba ba b a ID sffjhdsf32484 further part etc etc

Row adter update:

some text a ba ba b a  further part etc etc

how to achieve that?

I have following code up to now:

```
BEGIN
declare aaa anchor X.Y;
declare cur CURSOR for
    SELECT Y
    from X for update of Y;

open cur;

fetch cur into aaa;

update X.Y
set Y = //update logic
where current of cur;

close cur;
END;
```

unfortunatelly, It updates only first row in a table.

Comment: If your Db2 version+platform supports REGEXP_REPLACE then consider using that.  Plenty of examples online. Always tag your Db2 question with the correct platform tag for Z/os, LUW, or i-series because the SQL varies between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$ db2 "create table t(v varchar(2048))"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ db2 "insert into t values 'some text a ba ba b a ID sffjhdsf32484 further part etc etc'"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ db2 "update t set v = REGEXP_REPLACE(v,' ID sffjhdsf32484')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 "select v::varchar(60) from t"

1                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------
some text a ba ba b a further part etc etc                  

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP_REPLACE function as in the following example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('String containing ID skskskk999s inside',
'ID\s.*\s', '',1,1,'c') 
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer will be

```
1
------------------------
String containing inside
```

Knowing how REGEXP_REPLACE works, now you can use it in an UPDATE statement or any other statement you need.  For example

```
UPDATE TBL SET SPECIFIC_COLUMN = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    SPECIFIC_COLUMN,'ID\s.*\s', '',1,1,'c')
```